# reset autoincrement starting point

Tags: mysql, increment

I am having the following issue :

I have database where I auto increment the user id's starting from 001. Now, that I have completed 100 users, I want to auto increment the further id's from 1000 for some reasons.

How is it possible? Thanks in advance.

PS : I am using MYSQL, PHP and phpmyadmin.

Comment: BTW: Your leading zeroes is not a good idea

Comment: Try googling mysql reset auto increment

Comment: @bub Why so? Would it create an issue?

Comment: _PS : I am using MYSQL, PHP and phpmyadmin._ - That's what tags are for ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY some_column INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE tablew_name CHANGE id id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

OR

Select the A_I check box when creating/editing a column from your phpmyadmin UI.